# How to map usual key in insert mode?

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode

I want to bring some magic to my configuration but it fails to work because it seems Vim refuses to imap to a key in main keyboard. For example:

```
imap a bcd
```

I know most of time that's insane, but I have use case for that. Is there any switch for that so that I can turn this off?

Here is my Vim version:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Mar 31 2015 23:36:07)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "refuse"? What happens exactly?

Comment: @romainl just an `a` gets input in my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reason. I have `set paste` in my `.vimrc`, and according to the doc (`:h paste`) this option disable mappings in insert mode:

> When the 'paste' option is switched on (also when it was already on):
>   mapping in Insert mode and Command-line mode is disabled